# How to Mock ExecuteReader method?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, idatareader, stubs

I'm new to `moq` and setting up mocks so i could do with a little help. How do I mock up an `ExecuteReader()` using `Moq`?

Update

**I have below code for ExecuteReader**

```
    private void ExecuteGainLossCommand(AccountsContext dbContext, string query, MIS_GainLoss collGainLoss)
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                collGainLoss.collGainLoss = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<MIS_GainLossHolding>(reader).ToList<MIS_GainLossHolding>();
            }
            //Fetch Total's result set                          
            reader.NextResult();

            reader.NextResult();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                collGainLoss.collPurchaseData = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext)
                            .ObjectContext
                            .Translate<MIS_GainLossHolding>(reader).ToList<MIS_GainLossHolding>();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        finally 
        {
            dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

**This is a model**

```
    public class MIS_GainLoss
      {
          public ICollection<MIS_GainLossHolding> collGainLoss { get; set; }
          public ICollection<MIS_GainLossHolding> collPurchaseData = new List<MIS_GainLossHolding>();        
      }   



   public class MIS_GainLossHolding
     {         
        public Guid Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; } 
     }
```

**Below are the mock data which i want to mock in unit test**

```
      var holdings =
            new List<MIS_GainLoss>{
             new MIS_GainLoss
                {
                    collGainLoss = new[]
                        {
                            new MIS_GainLossHolding { 
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                Name = "ASTON/River Road Dividend All Cap Val N",
                                Symbol = "ARDEX",

                            },
                                new MIS_GainLossHolding { 
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                Name = "Champlain Mid Cap Adv",
                                Symbol = "CIPMX",

                            }
                        },
                    collPurchaseData = new[]
                        {
                            new MIS_GainLossHolding { 
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                Name = "ASTON/River Road Dividend All Cap Val N",
                                Symbol = "ARDEX",

                            },
                                new MIS_GainLossHolding { 
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                Name = "Champlain Mid Cap Adv",
                                Symbol = "CIPMX",

                            }
                        },
                }
    };
```

some pepole suggests **IDataReader** apporoch is it suitable for it and how can i implement?
How can i write unit test cases for this code

Comment: Have you considered mocking out the entire data access so that you would get back a list instead?

Comment: can you give me an example how to do that ?

Comment: You would separate out all code that has to do with SQL into a separate class, wrap it in an interface and then pass in the interface to the method. Standard dependency injection, there should be plenty of tutorials and articles on the web about this.

Comment: Hi @LasseV.Karlsen i don't have authority to changes this method 'ExecuteGainLossCommand'. I want to to create Testcases on that method. could you please suggest code for that?

Comment: @AjinkyaKasar, `ExecuteGainLossCommand` is poorly designed as it is tightly coupled to implementation details which do not allow for it to be easily tested in isolation. As it is currently written you will have to do integration-testing with an actual context. Consider redesigning that method.

Comment: If you cannot change it you cannot provide a mockup unless you use a kind of IL rewriting system, I would seriously look into getting access to modifying code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It would be greatful if u change d code **ExecuteGainLossCommand** give me unittest case also. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to do that. The experience of doing this is best learned.

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen but can you suggest some code changes or some approches to me for doing that?